# Sending status message from one class to my Main method

Tags: c#

I have a class with a lengthy `foreach` loop that may take a minute or even more to run, depending on number of records I am parsing and inserting, updating,etc..

So I have one class like this:

```
public class FileManeger
{

   public bool ParseFile()
   {
       // ....stuff
       foreach(DataRow row in Rows)
       {
            // stuff
       }
   }
}
```

and then in my `program.cs`  `main method`:

```
FileManager manager = new FileManager();
Console.Writeline("Parsing started...");
manager.ParseFile();
Console.Writeline("Parsing Finished.");
```

So I was thinking maybe in between of those two messages I can show a few more feedback, for example put a counter in that `foreach` loop and for every 50 rows that passes
print a console message like **"parsing rows 1 to 50 from 6500 rows",** "**parsing rows 51 to 100 from 6500 rows",** etc...

So I think I need to write some sort of `event` but I am not experienced with events, can someone help with that part?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the BackgroundWorker class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker

Comment: since you aren't familiar with events, why not just put a Console.Writeline in the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. You can use delegates.

```
public class FileManeger
{
   public Action<string> Trace {get;set;}
   public bool ParseFile()
   {
       // ....stuff
       foreach(DataRow row in Rows)
       {
            // stuff
            this.Trace("Send a message like this");

       }
   }
}
```

Then in your Main

```
FileManager manager = new FileManager();
Console.Writeline("Parsing started...");
manager.Trace = (msg)=>Console.WriteLine(msg);
new Thread(()=>{manager.ParseFile();}).Start();
//    Console.Writeline("Parsing Finished."); let the file parser emit this message
```

Comment: Thank you, That's the type of solution I was looking for.

Comment: "let the file parser emit this message" ... so you mean at the end of the ParseFile method?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to add more messages to the console then you can do it like this:

```
   public bool ParseFile()
   {
       // ....stuff
       int i = 1;
       int count = Rows.Count();
       foreach(DataRow row in Rows)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("parsing row " + i + " from " + count + " rows");
            ++i;
            // stuff
       }
   }
```

And of course if you want to add this message only for every 50 or so elements than change the Console.WriteLine part to this:

```
if (i%50 == 1) Console.WriteLine("parsing rows " + i + "-" + i+49 + " from " + count + " rows");
```

But I strongly encourage you to take a look at [BackgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) and/or [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)